# How to find the number of unordered pairs of 2D coordinate points, whose joining line passes through origin?

Tags: python, performance, math

(Original problem description)

Pair of points

You are given the following

An integer N

A 2D array of length N denoting the points in the 2D coordinate system, that is (x, y)

Task

Determine the number of unordered pairs (i, j) or (j, i) and i != j such that

The straight line connecting the points (A[i][1], A[i][2]) and (A[j][1], A[j][2]) passes through (0, 0)

(Context, this was a coding problem on hacker earth site and I did solve it (bruteforce) method)

My code:

```
def find_pairs(array, size):
    li = []
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            if (i, j) not in li and (j, i) not in li:
                if ((array[i][1] * (array[j][0] - array[i][0])) == ((array[i][0] * (array[j][1] - array[i][1]))):
                    li.append((i,j))
    return len(li)
```

The math the code uses is, given two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), their line passes through the origin if they satisfy the equation (x1 * (y2 - y1)) = (y1 * (x2 - x1))

This code passed half the test cases (which were testing for correct answer) but failed the remaining which had time constraint. I tried to use itertools.combinations but it exceeded the memory limit

Is there any way to write a program with less than N2 time complexity?

Comment: Consider that in order for a connecting line to pass through the origin (0,0), x1 = -ax2 and y1 = -by2, where a and b are non-negative scalars. Use this to reduce the search space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put tangent (slope) of line origin-to-point into `Counter` (in general - dictionary with value as counter for old Python without this class). Make separate counter for points with x=0 (vertical line).

After putting all slopes into the map, retieve number of pairs for every slope - `n` points with the same slope give `n*(n-1)/2` pairs

Linear complexity.

```
from collections import Counter
pts = [[1,0],[2,2],[-1,-1],[4,4],[0,2],[-2,0]]
vert = 0
cntr = Counter()
for p in pts:
    if p[0]:
        cntr[p[1]/p[0]] += 1
    else:
        vert += 1
res = vert * (vert - 1) // 2
for v in cntr.values():
    res += v*(v-1) // 2
print(res)  # 4 pairs
```

Update: accounts for (0,0):

```
from collections import Counter
pts = [[1,0],[2,2],[-1,-1],[4,4],[0,2],[-2,0],[0,0],[0,0]]
vert = 0
zeros = 0
cntr = Counter()
for p in pts:
    if p[0]:
        cntr[p[1]/p[0]] += 1
    else:
        if p[1]:
            vert += 1
        else:
            zeros += 1
res = vert * (vert - 1) // 2
for v in cntr.values():
    res += v*(v-1) // 2
res += (len(pts) - zeros) * zeros  + zeros*(zeros-1)//2
print(res) //17 pairs
```

Potential pitfall - float number comparison might give wrong results for some pairs.
If points are integers, it is possible to use integer tuple  `( sign(x)*y/gcd(y,x), abs(x)/gcd(x,y) )` as key

Comment: Well this almost works except for accomodating when (0,0) is present

Comment: Really missed this. Updated

Comment: Thanks man. You are an absolute genius! My code doesn't even work properly now that I discovered because precision is kinda lost during cross multiplication, example (95, -3) and (32, -1)

Comment: Cross multiplication should work fine. Seems you need x1*y2==x2*y1, not differences

Comment: It isn't working though, (95 * -1) which is -95 and (32 * -3) which is -96. I checked using desmos and the lines do form a straight line. Their decimal slopes are not precisely equal though. And I've run my code snippet vs yours, with the test case [[77, -29], [32, -1], [-10, -73], [-86, -47], [95, -3], [30, -41]]. Mine shows 0 and yours shows 1 as output. I'm not rounding in both the cases

Comment: My code gives 0 for the last list.  (95 * -1) and (32 * -3) don't belong to the same ray despite of it looks so.

Answer (score 1):

One optimization we can make in your code is not to check previously traversed co-ordinates:

```py
def find_pairs(array, size):
    count = 0
    for i in range(size - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, size):
            if ((array[i][1] * (array[j][0] - array[i][0])) == ((array[i][0] * (array[j][1] - array[i][1]))):
                count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

If using `itertools.combinations` exceeded your memory limit then you used it incorrectly. The functions in the `itertools` library are generally quite memory efficient because they work with iterators rather than creating complete lists in memory.

```py
num_pairs = 0
for i, j in itertools.combinations(array, 2):
    if i_j_are_valid_points():  # your formula here
        num_pairs += 2          # (i, j) and (j, i) are both valid
```

Note that this is still O(N^2) - you can't find all combinations of pairs in less time. But it will run over twice as fast as your solution since: 1) it doesn't check both (i, j) and (j, i) redundantly; 2) it doesn't need to traverse the list of already found solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you can do this in O(NlogN) (merge sort) time, at least in theory. If you convert to polar coordinates, then you're looking for two points (r_1, theta) and (r_2, theta + pi) so you can just sort them and then process from theta in [0, pi), and compare with those from theta in [pi, 2pi). If you use floating point numbers though, you'll need to be careful how you compare the two values because floating point values are only stored approximately.

Comment: So it's like calculating slope for each line joining the point and origin and then finding pairs with same slope? And when you said merge sort, is there a divide and conquer approach to this?

Comment: I think you'll struggle to get better than O(NlogN) if you want to actually identify the lines that pass through the origin. I'm not familiar with the Counter() function in the other answer, but they appear to be assuming new points can be included in constant O(1) time. It only gives a count and doesn't tell you which are the points. Don't know about a divide and conquer approach. Feel free to have a go.

Comment: The count approach works perfectly. It gives a count of the slopes which occur more than once and finally an unordered pair is calculated from that (using combinations formulae)

Comment: The points in the example are all small powers of two. I don't think it would work well in general for lots of points with any integer or float values in the coordinates.

Comment: But isn't the time complexity what matters here? And isn't its time complexity O(N)? Floating points is a limitation, but it's alright to ignore it for now

Comment: Time Complexity is secondary to it working. I commented about the time complexity earlier.